# Test the value of a deeply nested property using Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test to see if some value gets set to 0 with the following code and test:

**Code:**

```js
this.customShell.customShellApp.element.nativeElement.scrollTop = 0;
```

**Test:**

```js
spyOnProperty(component.customShellApp, 'element', 'set').and.returnValue({
  nativeElement: { scrollTop: 0 }
});
expect(component.customShellApp.element.nativeElement.scrollTop).toBe(0);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```js
Error: <spyOnProperty> : spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for element
```

Anybody know how I can test the full property? The property comes from a `CustomShellBase` which we extend.

Full code below:

**AppComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, Injector, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Event, NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CustomShellBase, CustomShellService } from 'custom-shell-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent extends CustomShellBase implements OnDestroy {
  loading = false;

  protected destroyed$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  constructor(
    protected injector: Injector,
    private router: Router,
    protected shellService: CustomShellService
  ) {
    super(injector);

    this.router.events
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
      .subscribe((event: Event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          this.customShell.customShellApp.element.nativeElement.scrollTop = 0;
          this.loading = false;
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroyed$.next(true);
    this.destroyed$.complete();
  }
}
```

**AppComponent.spec.ts**

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  let shellNavService: CustomShellNavService;
  let router: Router;

  const eventSubject = new ReplaySubject<RouterEvent>(1);
  const routerMock = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate'),
    events: eventSubject.asObservable(),
    url: 'test/url'
  };
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      providers: [
        CustomShellService,
        { provide: CustomShellNavService, useClass: MockCustomShellNavService },
        { provide: Router, useValue: routerMock },
      ],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    shellNavService = TestBed.inject(CustomShellNavService);
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
  });

  it('should set the loading on FALSE and scroll to the top when a NavigationEnd event happens', () => {
    eventSubject.next(new NavigationEnd(1, '', ''));
    spyOnProperty(component.customShellApp, 'element', 'set').and.returnValue({
      nativeElement: { scrollTop: 0 }
    });
    expect(component.customShellApp.element.nativeElement.scrollTop).toBe(0);
    expect(component.loading).toBeFalsy();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to directly change the property of customShellApp instead of using spyOnProperty

```
it('should set the loading on FALSE and scroll to the top when a NavigationEnd event happens', () => {
    // this should be mocked before the eventSubject.next
    (component as any).customShellApp = {
      element: {
        nativeElement: {
          scrollTop: 0
        }
      }
    };
    eventSubject.next(new NavigationEnd(1, '', ''));
    expect(component.customShellApp.element.nativeElement.scrollTop).toBe(0);
    expect(component.loading).toBeFalsy();
  });
```

If `customShellApp` is private, it can be difficult to assert